# I have many checkbox it render as the description below I want to change the nested value its in blue circle in the pic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

**This is my state:**
[view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXGVU.png)
the part in the circle is the part of the state that I want to change

**This is my checkbox input **

```
{this.state.data.map((elm) => (
    <div className={classes.rowContainer}>
      <h3>{elm.name}</h3>
      {elm.groupes.map((group) => (
        <input
          className={classes.checkBox}
          name={elm.name}
          groupes={group.groupName}
          checked={group.value}
          type='checkbox'
          onChange={this.changeValue}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
))}
```

This is the object passed to component:

```
 const data = [
  {
    name: 'Créer un groupe',
    groupes: [
      { name: 'commercial', value: true },
      { name: 'manager', value: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Détruire un groupe ',
    groupes: [
      { name: 'commercial', value: false },
      { name: 'manager', value: false }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Please post your `data` state array as text instead of a picture.

Comment: data : [0: {name: "Créer un groupe", groupes: [{name:commercial , value : true },{name:manager , value : true }]}
1: {name: "Détruire un groupe", groupes: [{name:commercial , value : true },{name:manager , value : true }]}
2: {name: "Modifier les groupes et leurs droits", groupes:[{name:commercial , value : true },{name:manager , value : true }]]

Comment: Did something change? This does not look like the screenshot, nothing here is called `groupName` and all the `value`s changed to `true`.

Comment: The data shown in the question and the data shown in the screenshot are different data. Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]. That should show the component definition in addition to its usage.

Comment: data = [
    {
      name: "Créer un groupe",
      groupes: [
        { name: "commercial", value: true },
        { name: "manager", value: false },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "Détruire un groupe ",
      groupes: [
        { name: "commercial", value: false },
        { name: "manager", value: false },
      ],
    },
  
  ];

Comment: this is a transh of the state

Comment: Can you show us what you current version of `this.changeValue` looks like?

Comment: i try many ways but didnt work so i deleted it and im thinking of another solution hope you could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the specific boolean `value` for a given checkbox, you can make use of the `.map()` calls indexes from the arrays, and pass those to the `onChange` handler of the checkbox inputs to update the correct value in the state.

To update the state itself safely and without mutation, you'll need to deep copy the `data` array (using a round trip through JSON in this case), then update the right value using the indexes, then assign the new data to the state.

Here is a working snippet that illustrates how this works:

```js
const data = [{
    name: 'Créer un groupe',
    groupes: [
        { name: 'commercial', value: true },
        { name: 'manager', value: false }
    ]
}, {
    name: 'Détruire un groupe ',
    groupes: [
        { name: 'commercial', value: false },
        { name: 'manager', value: false }
    ]
}];
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { data };
    }
    changeValue = (sectionIndex, groupIndex) => {
        const dataCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.data));
        const group = dataCopy[sectionIndex].groupes[groupIndex];
        group.value = !group.value;
        this.setState({ data: dataCopy });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                { this.state.data.map((elm, i) => (
                    <div key={`${i}`}>
                        <h3>{elm.name}</h3>
                        { elm.groupes.map((group, j) => (
                            <input key={`${i}${j}`} name={elm.name}
                                   checked={group.value} type="checkbox"
                                   onChange={() => this.changeValue(i, j)} />
                        )) }
                    </div>
                )) }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```